# Invalid regular expression error in angular directive

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

**Condition:**

Contents can only contain characters from the following set:

*a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
/ - ? : ( ) . , ' +*

• Contents may NOT begin with ‘/’
• Contents may NOT contain ‘//’

```
export function directDebitValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
            const directDebitID = nameRe.test(control.value);
            return directDebitID ? { 'directDebit': { value: control.value } } : null;
        };
    }
    
    @Directive({
        selector: '[directDebit]',
        providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DirectDebitValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
    })
    export class DirectDebitValidatorDirective  {
        validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
            
            return control.value ? directDebitValidator(new RegExp("^(? !.* [\/]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9-?:().,'+]+([a-zA-Z0-9\/-?:().,'+])*$"))(control)
                : null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The issue is the first questionmark. It's an invalid regexp. Either remove it or escape it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- There cannot be spaces in the lookahead definition
- The `[/-?]` creates a range, the `-` must be escaped or placed at the start/end of the character class.
- You may use a `/` unescaped in the constructor notation since no delimiters are being used there.

So, you may use

```
directDebitValidator(new RegExp("^(?!.*/{2})[a-zA-Z0-9?:().,'+-][a-zA-Z0-9/?:().,'+-]*$"))
```

Or, using a regex literal notation:

```
directDebitValidator(/^(?!.*\/{2})[a-zA-Z0-9?:().,'+-][a-zA-Z0-9\/?:().,'+-]*$/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1lB9CO/1).